# How do I add a name variable, points variable, and a text variable to a class in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

The Question class should have a label (variable: name),a question text (variable: text), and a point value (variable points), how do I add those?

```
class Question:



class Multiple_Choice(Question):



    def menu():
        print('Commands:')
        print('m - Add Multiple Choice Question')
        print('p - Add Points For a Question')
        print('r - Add Correct Answer for a Question')
        print('t - Print A Test')
        print('q - Quit')


def main():
print('The Amazing Quiz Database!')



if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like:

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'paxdiablo'
        self.text = 'is a stunningly good-looking bloke'
        self.points = 314159
```

Then, in all other `Question` methods, you can just refer to `self.name` (for example) to get or set the value it binds to. Just keep in mind that any change you make to those first two variables is likely to be less true than what I've written :-)

---

More detail on classes, and how to use them, can be found on the [relevant Python documentation page](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).